# Lighting on a LED on KL64Z - ARM Cortex M0+

Tags: assembly, led, keil, cortex-m, cpu-registers

Having these addresses:

```
; - User data section -------------------------------------
AREA    UserData, DATA, READONLY

LEDS                EQU 0x4000703C   ; access PD3-PD0
GPIO_PORTD_DOR      EQU 0xF80FF0C0
GPIO_PORTD_PSOR     EQU 0xF80FF0C4
GPIO_PORTD_PCOR     EQU 0xF80FF0C8
GPIO_PORTD_PTOR     EQU 0xF80FF0CC
GPIO_PORTD_PDIR     EQU 0xF80FF0D0
GPIO_PORTD_PDDR     EQU 0xF80FF0D4
GPIO_PORTD_PCR      EQU 0x4004c004
SIM_BASE_SCG5       EQU 0x40048038
SYSCTL_RCGC2_GPIOD  EQU 0x1000   ; port D Clock Gating Control
PORT_PCR_MUX        EQU 0X100
```

How can I turn on a LED that it is on bit 5 of port D?

Comment: Just use [codewarrior](http://www.nxp.com/products/software-and-tools/software-development-tools/codewarrior-development-tools:CW_HOME), you can program in C. It has handy tools to set these things up.   *Disclaimer: Might be the wrong link, sorry.  Disclaimer II: I have a KL25Z.*

Comment: Also, why are you programming in assembly in the first place?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know how to do it in C, but now I've been asked to do it in assembly directly. For programming it in C I was using Keil.

Comment: Alright, good luck with that. I can't help you from here. Should I add an answer for the people who clicked on the fifth google result for `kl64z blink led`?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am trying to find the solution, when I do it I will post it here.

Comment: When posting a question about assembly, always tag the architecture. The KL64x should be *ARM Cortex M0+*. If you can do it in C, try translating it to assembly and post the result here. I guess it's all boils down to loading/performing bit operations/storing. Also if you have a C compiler why not simply take a look at it's output to have some insights?

Comment: Nice idea, I will try to copy the C compiler outputs. Thanks!!